# MVVM Light EventToCommand fails to pass Command Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm-light

Please help me how to solve this problem. i've been trying to solve this my self for almost two days. i've been searching for a problem similar to mine and trying to work for the solution suggested, but the error is still the same. I want to pass the Object `canvas` to my view Model when i clicked the Image control but its not working.

My View Model received

```
System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs
```

this is my View

```
<Grid>
            <Image  x:Name="img"  Source="{Binding ImagePath, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" Stretch="None" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                        <command:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cnvas}" Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand, Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListRectangle, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas   x:Name="cnvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=ActualHeight}"
                        LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=LayoutTransform}" >
                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Blue"  Fill="Transparent" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

and this is how it looks like in Run time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoEOk.png)

And this is the code for my View Model

```
public RelayCommand<object> MouseDownCommand { get; private set; }
        public ResizerVM()
        {
            MouseDownCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(MouseDownEvent);
        }

        private void MouseDownEvent(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Called");
                if (obj == null) return;
                Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

When I add the Trigger to my Canvas it doesn't execute. It only execute when i click the rectangle drawn in canvas. Which is opposite to what i Need

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Good day @aaron the View Model received System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs and not the Canvas

Comment: @aaron i don't understand. Can you please share a sample code? You mean i add code behind code?

Comment: Your trigger is in `Image` — put it in `Canvas`.

Comment: I also tried it but the trigger is only executed when i click on the rectangle drawn in the canvas. And which is opposite of what i need. Thank you. Please see the screenshot. I updated the question. I need to draw Another Rectangle using Mouse Event.

Comment: Try `private void MouseDownEvent(object obj, MouseButtonEventArgs e)`

Comment: Thank you. I already solve the problem with the event. The event is not working. So i added the canvas Background="Transparent" and now the event is working

Comment: If your answer is worth sharing, post it as an answer.